# Animation CSS3 does not work on this hover image

Tags: css, animation, background, css-transitions, css-animations

I have an image which its background changes in hover and I want to add hover to it.

here is what I want to add:

```
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

And it is the online version:
   http://jsfiddle.net/jmXdh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/jmXdh/5/)**

This is the solution that you are searching for!

```
HTML CHANGES
<a href="/">
<img class="imghover" src="http://i42.tinypic.com/2v9zuc1.jpg"/>
<img class="img" src="http://i40.tinypic.com/i3s4dc.png"/>
</a>

CSS IMPROVEMENTS
.img{
    z-index:1;
    margin-left: -190px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;
}
.img:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
.imghover{
    z-index:-100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS properties can't be animated, including `background-image`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: Yh i thought about that, but I have an image tag in my code, can't I animate that?

Comment: @AlexJj Afraid not, in general the only things you can animate are numerical values or colors.